# Count occurrence of byte pattern in binary file

Tags: c#, hex

I want my program to read hex value of a binary file and count the occurrence '45' and now stuck on counting byte pattern.

```
public static byte[] GetOccurrence(string dump)
{
    using (BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(dump, FileMode.Open)))
    {
        bufferB = new byte[32];
        b.BaseStream.Seek(0x000000, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        b.Read(bufferB, 0, 32);
        return bufferB;
    }
}  

bufferA = GetOccurrence(textOpen.Text);   // textOpen.Text is the opened file

// bufferA now stores 53 4F 4E 59 20 43 4F 4D 50 55 54 45 52 20 45 4E 54 45 52 54 41 49 4E 4D 45 4E 54 20 49 4E 43 2E

// trying to count occurrence of '45' and display the total occurrence in textbox
```

Comment: What is your difficulty? just counting the number of occurrences in the array or you also not sure about reading from the file?

Comment: If provided answer has helped, etiquette is to mark this as "the answer" and probably upvote its usefulness. 
This prevents this question coming up under "show unanswered questions" in SOF and also gives some more reputation to the person who helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop trough each element in the array and count each time the value 45 is found. Or you can use LINQ Count and achieve the same result.

Here I have made both implementations:

```
        var bufferA = new byte[] { 53, 0x4F, 0x4E, 59, 20, 43, 0x4F, 0x4D, 50, 55, 54, 45, 52, 20, 45, 0x4E, 54, 45, 52, 54, 41, 49, 0x4E, 0x4D, 45, 0x4E, 54, 20, 49, 0x4E, 43, 0x2E };
        //Using LINQ
        var numOfRepetition = bufferA.Count(x=> x== 45);

        //Using a foreach loop
        var count = 0;
        foreach(byte number in bufferA)
        {
            if(number == 45)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
```

In both implementations the number 45 is repeated 4 times.